# Using include inside loop to send mail

Tags: php, html

I am trying to have my loop insert into the database 6 records automatically, the only thing that changes is the dates of these records, and whenever it enters it has to send an email with the always updated data, but the only one thing I got was to make it send only 1 email, and this email only has the last loop information.

The idea is to send an email whenever you insert it into the DB

Here is the code test:

```
<?php
$replace1="27-02-2019 00:00";
$replace2="27-02-2029 00:00";
$strStart = '2019-09-10';
$strEnd = '2029-09-10'; 
$dteStart = new DateTime($strStart); 
$dteEnd   = new DateTime($strEnd); 
$dteDiff  = $dteStart->diff($dteEnd); 
$anos=$dteDiff->format("%Y");
$dias=$dteDiff->format("%d");
$meses=$dteDiff->format("%m");
$repete = ($anos * 12);
$rotina="6";
if($rotina == "6"){
    $assunto = "Rotina Semestral";
    $repete = ($repete / 6);
     for($i = 0; $i <= $repete; $i++){
        echo $i."==".$replace1." - ";
        echo $replace2."<br>";
        $replace1 = date('d-m-Y H:m',strtotime($replace1." +6 Months")); 
        include('email1.php');
    };
}elseif($rotina == "3"){
   //code...
   };
}elseif($rotina == "1"){
    $repete = $anos;
     for($i = 0; $i <= $repete; $i++){
        //code... 
    };    
};
```

Here is `email1.php`:

```
<?php
 $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '\dist\PHPMailer_5.2.0\\';
 $file = $path . 'class.phpmailer.php';
 include($file);

   $mail = new PHPMailer();
   $mail->CharSet = 'UTF8';

   $mail->IsSMTP();
   $mail->Host = "$smtp";
   $mail->SMTPAuth = false;

    $mail->From = "$emailhost";
    $mail->FromName = "Nova tarefa  SIGMA ";
    $mail->AddAddress ($email_post);

    $mail->WordWrap = 99999;
    $mail->IsHTML(true);


    $mail->Subject = "Nova tarefa SIGMA WO/NF/ID Cliente: ".$won1;
    $mail->AddEmbeddedImage('img/baixo.png', 'baixo');
    $mail->Body    = "<div style='margin-left:0px; padding:0px;width:800px;height:772px;style='color:#3366FF;'>
    <h1 style='text-align: center; background-color:#0B95ED; color:#FFFFFF;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:2.5em;'>Informação do Pedido - Novo Pedido</h1>
    <hr><br>

    <!-- texto entre linhas -->
      <table align='center' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%' id='templateColumns'>
      <tr>
          <td align='center' valign='top' width='50%' class=' '>
              <table border='0' cellpadding='10' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>
                  <tr>
                      <td class='leftColumnContent' bgcolor='#B0C4DE'>
                      <b>WO/NF/ID Cliente: 
                      </td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                      <td class='leftColumnContent' bgcolor=''>
                      <!-- WO/NF/ID Cliente: -->
                      $won
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td class='leftColumnContent' bgcolor='#B0C4DE'>
                      <b>Responsável do pedido:
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td class='leftColumnContent' bgcolor=''>
                      <!-- Responsável do pedido:  -->
                      $res_2
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td class='leftColumnContent' bgcolor='#B0C4DE'>
                      <b>Técnico 1: 
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td class='leftColumnContent' bgcolor=''>
                      <!-- Técnico 2:  -->
                      $tec1_1
                      </td>
                  </tr>
              </table>
          </td>
          <td align='center' valign='top' width='50%' class=' '>
              <table border='0' cellpadding='10' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>
              <tr>
                      <td class='rightColumnContent' bgcolor='#B0C4DE'>
                     <b> Cliente: 
                      </td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                      <td class='rightColumnContent' bgcolor=''>
                      $cli
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td class='rightColumnContent' bgcolor='#B0C4DE'>
                      <font color='#B0C4DE'>Vazio</font>
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td class='rightColumnContent' bgcolor=''>
                      <font color='#FFFFFF'>Vazio</font>
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td class='rightColumnContent' bgcolor='#B0C4DE'>
                      <b>Técnico 2: 
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td class='rightColumnContent' bgcolor=''>
                      $tec2_2
                      </td>
                  </tr>
              </table>
          </td>

  </table>
  <table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'  width='100%' id='templateColumns'>
      <tr>
          <td align='center' valign='top' width='100%' class=' '>
              <table border='0' cellpadding='10' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>
                  <tr>
                      <td class='leftColumnContent' bgcolor='#B0C4DE'>
                      <b>Descrição da Tarefa:
                      </td>
                  </tr>
              </table>
          </td>        
      </tr>
  </table>
  <table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'  width='100%' id='templateColumns'>
      <tr>
          <td align='center' valign='top' width='100%' class=' '>
              <table border='0' cellpadding='10' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>
                  <tr>
                      <td class='leftColumnContent' bgcolor=''>
                      <div class='b'>
                      $descre
                      </div>                     
                      </td>
                  </tr>
              </table>
          </td>        
      </tr>
  </table>

    <div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
    <tr>
      <td><center>
        <div>
          <!--[if mso]>
            <v:roundrect xmlns:v='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml' xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word' href='http://sigma.eda.pt' style='height:36px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:150px;' arcsize='5%' strokecolor='#EB7035' fillcolor='#EB7035'>
              <w:anchorlock/>
              <center style='color:#ffffff;font-family:Helvetica, Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;'>Bom Trabalho! &rarr;</center>
            </v:roundrect>
          <![endif]-->
          <a href='http://sigma.eda.pt' style='background-color:#EB7035;border:1px solid #EB7035;border-radius:3px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:16px;line-height:44px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:150px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all;'>Bom Trabalho! &rarr;</a>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  ";
                   $mail->Send();
```

Comment: There is also in php the mail function but i have not used it so i don't know the risks of using it.

Comment: move the include out of the loop and make the content of the include (email1.php) a function . after that call the function inside the loop. Replace your if whit switch http://php.net/manual/en/control-structures.switch.php

Comment: @scaff can you please make an exemple code to test?

Comment: @NoobDEV-GBL post the content of your email1.php file

Comment: @scaff i have added the code from email1.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I cant't test it for the moment but the new file will be something like this

```
<?php
 $path = $_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'] . '\dist\PHPMailer_5.2.0\\';
 $file = $path . 'class.phpmailer.php';
 **include_once($file);**
 function my_send_mail($smtp,$emailhost,$email_post,$won1,$won,$res_2,$tec1_1,$cli,$tec2_2,$descre){
   $mail = new PHPMailer();
   $mail->CharSet = 'UTF8';

   $mail->IsSMTP();
   $mail->Host = "$smtp";
   $mail->SMTPAuth = false;

    $mail->From = "$emailhost";
    $mail->FromName = "Nova tarefa  SIGMA ";
    $mail->AddAddress ($email_post);

    $mail->WordWrap = 99999;
    $mail->IsHTML(true);


    $mail->Subject = "Nova tarefa SIGMA WO/NF/ID Cliente: ".$won1;
    $mail->AddEmbeddedImage('img/baixo.png', 'baixo');
    $mail->Body    = "<div style='margin-left:0px; padding:0px;width:800px;height:772px;style='color:#3366FF;'>
    <h1 style='text-align: center; background-color:#0B95ED; color:#FFFFFF;font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;line-height:2.5em;'>Informação do Pedido - Novo Pedido</h1>
    <hr><br>

    <!-- texto entre linhas -->
      <table align='center' border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0' width='100%' id='templateColumns'>
      <tr>
          <td align='center' valign='top' width='50%' class=' '>
              <table border='0' cellpadding='10' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>
                  <tr>
                      <td class='leftColumnContent' bgcolor='#B0C4DE'>
                      <b>WO/NF/ID Cliente: 
                      </td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                      <td class='leftColumnContent' bgcolor=''>
                      <!-- WO/NF/ID Cliente: -->
                      $won
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td class='leftColumnContent' bgcolor='#B0C4DE'>
                      <b>Responsável do pedido:
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td class='leftColumnContent' bgcolor=''>
                      <!-- Responsável do pedido:  -->
                      $res_2
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td class='leftColumnContent' bgcolor='#B0C4DE'>
                      <b>Técnico 1: 
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td class='leftColumnContent' bgcolor=''>
                      <!-- Técnico 2:  -->
                      $tec1_1
                      </td>
                  </tr>
              </table>
          </td>
          <td align='center' valign='top' width='50%' class=' '>
              <table border='0' cellpadding='10' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>
              <tr>
                      <td class='rightColumnContent' bgcolor='#B0C4DE'>
                     <b> Cliente: 
                      </td>
                  </tr>

                  <tr>
                      <td class='rightColumnContent' bgcolor=''>
                      $cli
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td class='rightColumnContent' bgcolor='#B0C4DE'>
                      <font color='#B0C4DE'>Vazio</font>
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td class='rightColumnContent' bgcolor=''>
                      <font color='#FFFFFF'>Vazio</font>
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td class='rightColumnContent' bgcolor='#B0C4DE'>
                      <b>Técnico 2: 
                      </td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                      <td class='rightColumnContent' bgcolor=''>
                      $tec2_2
                      </td>
                  </tr>
              </table>
          </td>

  </table>
  <table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'  width='100%' id='templateColumns'>
      <tr>
          <td align='center' valign='top' width='100%' class=' '>
              <table border='0' cellpadding='10' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>
                  <tr>
                      <td class='leftColumnContent' bgcolor='#B0C4DE'>
                      <b>Descrição da Tarefa:
                      </td>
                  </tr>
              </table>
          </td>        
      </tr>
  </table>
  <table border='0' cellpadding='0' cellspacing='0'  width='100%' id='templateColumns'>
      <tr>
          <td align='center' valign='top' width='100%' class=' '>
              <table border='0' cellpadding='10' cellspacing='0' width='100%'>
                  <tr>
                      <td class='leftColumnContent' bgcolor=''>
                      <div class='b'>
                      $descre
                      </div>                     
                      </td>
                  </tr>
              </table>
          </td>        
      </tr>
  </table>

    <div>
  </div>
  <hr>
  <table width='100%' border='0' cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
    <tr>
      <td><center>
        <div>
          <!--[if mso]>
            <v:roundrect xmlns:v='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:vml' xmlns:w='urn:schemas-microsoft-com:office:word' href='http://sigma.eda.pt' style='height:36px;v-text-anchor:middle;width:150px;' arcsize='5%' strokecolor='#EB7035' fillcolor='#EB7035'>
              <w:anchorlock/>
              <center style='color:#ffffff;font-family:Helvetica, Arial,sans-serif;font-size:16px;'>Bom Trabalho! &rarr;</center>
            </v:roundrect>
          <![endif]-->
          <a href='http://sigma.eda.pt' style='background-color:#EB7035;border:1px solid #EB7035;border-radius:3px;color:#ffffff;display:inline-block;font-family:sans-serif;font-size:16px;line-height:44px;text-align:center;text-decoration:none;width:150px;-webkit-text-size-adjust:none;mso-hide:all;'>Bom Trabalho! &rarr;</a>
        </div>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  ";
                   $mail->Send();
 }
```

and your default file will be

```
<?php
include('email1.php');
$replace1="27-02-2019 00:00";
$replace2="27-02-2029 00:00";
$strStart = '2019-09-10';
$strEnd = '2029-09-10'; 
$dteStart = new DateTime($strStart); 
$dteEnd   = new DateTime($strEnd); 
$dteDiff  = $dteStart->diff($dteEnd); 
$anos=$dteDiff->format("%Y");
$dias=$dteDiff->format("%d");
$meses=$dteDiff->format("%m");
$repete = ($anos * 12);
$rotina="6";
switch($rotina){
case "6":
    $assunto = "Rotina Semestral";
    $repete = ($repete / 6);
     for($i = 0; $i <= $repete; $i++){
        echo $i."==".$replace1." - ";
        echo $replace2."<br>";
        $replace1 = date('d-m-Y H:m',strtotime($replace1." +6 Months")); 

        my_send_mail($smtp,$emailhost,$email_post,$won1,$won,$res_2,$tec1_1,$cli,$tec2_2,$descre);
    };
    break;
case "3":
   //code...
break;
case "1":
    $repete = $anos;
     for($i = 0; $i <= $repete; $i++){
        //code... 
    };    
break;
}
```

But i don't know where you take the variable used inside the file mail1.php

I don't know what php lib you are using for sendmail but implemente exceptions in mail send http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php

Sorry for my bad english

Replace

```
$mail->Send()
```

whit this

```
try {
  if ( !$mail->Send() ) {
    $error = "Unable to send to: " . $to . "<br />";
    throw new phpmailerAppException($error);
  } else {
    echo 'Message has been sent using <?php echo strtoupper($_POST['test_type']); ?><br /><br />';
  }
} catch (phpmailerAppException $e) {
  $errorMsg[] = $e->errorMessage();
}

if ( count($errorMsg) > 0 ) {
  foreach ($errorMsg as $key => $value) {
    $thisError = $key + 1;
    echo $thisError . ': ' . $value;
  }
}
```

Comment: i'm going to test it now, to see if that worcks, because i have been testing that by 2 day's and no results

Comment: i have made the test, and i got error 500, i copy/paste your exemple

Comment: enable error and show me your error probably the function parameters, i repeat i don't know where you take the variable used inside the file mail1.php  every one of this  vars are not set $smtp,$emailhost,$email_post,$won1,$won,$res_2,$tec1_1,$cli,$tec2_2,$descre

Comment: the error is {
 "resource": "/c:/Users/pc/AppData/Local/Temp/fz3temp-2/teste.php",
 "owner": "_generated_diagnostic_collection_name_#1",
 "code": "1",
 "severity": 8,
 "message": "Unexpected 'case'.",
 "source": "intelephense",
 "startLineNumber": 34,
 "startColumn": 5,
 "endLineNumber": 34,
 "endColumn": 9
}

Comment: fixed,you forgot a ";}" before break...
 but the problem is the same, i only got 1 email from 2 records....

Comment: use exceptions to find why lib don't send mail http://php.net/manual/en/language.exceptions.php see your lib docs

Comment: i have no error on exeptions, 
it seems that the loop only implements the function of sending the email 1 time and not every cycle

Comment: i have implemented my answer with exceptions try to do it and give me feedback

Comment: do you have php error enable? Does the result print only 2 lines?? I have test the loop and it give me back about 20 line so probably you have an error in another line inside function.

Comment: and you are able to sent 20 emails?, yes i have php erros enable, my loop is broken wen uses email funcion 2ºtime...

Comment: no i'm unable to send mail because i haven't your full code. but the loop give me back about 20 line

Comment: change mail library i have used this https://github.com/PHPMailer/PHPMailer

Comment: add this lines at the start of your script to be sure that there are no error error_reporting(-1);
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
set_error_handler("var_dump");

Comment: well, the error log is now : 'Fatal error: Cannot declare class phpmailerException, because the name is already in use' when doing the loop on second time

Comment: try to change every include with include_once and every require with require_once

Comment: you was right, on the email funcion i changet to include_once the class.phpmailer.php and it works well